# Connecting to a WebSocket using Play! 2.5

Tags: java, websocket, playframework

I am trying to connect to a WebSocket service from my Play! Application.

There is actually a library to do this for this scenario, but it used `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient` which interferes with the internal akka system of Play! (it stops it)

However, I don't seem to grasp how to do this myself. I normally use WSClient when I initiate a connection, but WSClient doesn't have a provision for Websockets (it throws an error `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No WebSocketUpgradeHandler but scheme is wss`)

I can find a lot of information on how to create a WebSocket that listens, but not one that connects.

Is there a mechanism integrated with Play! that can easily do that, or a library that is safe to use?
Any help is really appreciated.